# Adding 2 html files to my one-page scrolling site

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate, vertical-scrolling

I'm adding 2 html files to my one-page scrolling site (index.html). I'm having issues with the navbar (bootstrap). When "booking form" of "faq" are clicked the page is not transfering over to a selected html file due to scrolling feature on the included index.html. How do I fix this?

I've tried adding a class to #home, #service, #corporate and #contact  links and adding the same class to the Jquery function behind "navbar a". It works that way but the scrolling on index.html is gone then.

index.html navbar:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-offset="80">
  <div id="nav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top menu-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">LOGO</a>
          </div>
          <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <nav>
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a class="page-scroll" href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#service">Services</a></li>
                <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#corporate">Corporate</a></li>
                <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="bookingform.html">Booking Form</a></li>
                <li><a href="faqs.html">FAQ</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--- END COL -->
      </div>
      <!--- END COL -->
    </div>
    <!--- END CONTAINER -->
  </div>
```

faqs.html navbar:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-offset="80">
    <div id="nav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top menu-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
                            data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">LOGO</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                        <nav>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li><a href="index.html#home">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="index.html#service">Services</a></li>
                                <li><a href="index.html#corporate">Corporate</a></li>
                                <li><a href="index.html#contact">Contact</a></li>
                                <li><a href="bookingform.html">Booking Form</a></li>
                                <li class="active"><a href="faqs.html">FAQ</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--- END COL -->
            </div>
            <!--- END COL -->
        </div>
        <!--- END CONTAINER -->
    </div>
```

Jquery function at the begining of js file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('select').niceSelect();

    // Add smooth scrolling to all links in navbar + footer link
    $(".navbar a, footer a[href='#myPage'], .overlay-detail a").on('click', function (event) {

        // Prevent default anchor click behavior
        event.preventDefault();

        // Store hash
        var hash = this.hash;

        // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
        // The optional number (900) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
        }, 900, function () {

            // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
            window.location.hash = hash;
        });
    });
```

Here is the error I'm getting in console when BookingForm or FAQ tab is clicked in navbar:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined    app.js:17 
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (app.js:17)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Some of your elements give hash=" ";
COuld you try to modify you as below and try

```
{
        var currentpage = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop();
        var nextpage = this.href.split("/").pop();
        if ("".search("#" > -1)) {
          nextpage = nextpage.split("#")[0];
        }
        if (this.hash != "" && currentpage == nextpage) {
          //prevent default only if  required
          // pages are different AND has hash
          event.preventDefault();
          // Store hash
          var hash = this.hash;
          // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
          // The optional number (900) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
          $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
          }, 900, function () {
            // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
            window.location.hash = hash;
          });
        }
        else
        {
          //
        }
      }
```

Comment: it's not working. it console.logs the <a href="faqs.html">FAQ</a>     app.js 26

Comment: im pretty sure this is the answer

Comment: so it should look like this:

Comment: <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a class="page-scroll" href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#service">Services</a></li>
                <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#corporate">Corporate</a></li>
                <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a class="page-scroll" href="bookingform.html#form">Booking Form</a></li>
                <li><a class="page-scroll" href="faqs.html#faq">FAQ</a></li>
              </ul>

Comment: what am I missing?

Comment: window.location.href =this.href;////******Redirect TO your Page<-----insetead of console log..page will be transfered

Comment: @Bojan Mitrovic  ...remember at top when you were getting  <a href="faqs.html">FAQ</a>  ....so instead of logging  it we could use  window.location.href =this.href;////******Redirect TO your Page<-----

Comment: thank you. this way when I'm on index.html page it redirects to bookingform.html or faqs.html when selected but once on those two pages I'm getting an error when I try to go back to home page. How should href on bookingform.html and faqs.html look?

Comment: Updated the code & also  DEMO: http://plnkr.co/edit/rF7oozQ4Lsf1aneFrhEr?p=preview i have created a demo here

Comment: Thank you Kunal, this worked fine. Is there any way to have a smoother transition when going back to index.html from the two additional html files?

Comment: try answer  below

Answer (score 0):

Try this

ADD Following to your document ready of pages where you want such effect

to have a smoother transition when going back to index.html from the two additional html files

````
      var hash=location.hash;
      if (location.hash!='') {
      window.scrollTo(0,0);
      $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
          }, 900, function () {
            // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
            window.location.hash = hash;
          });
      }
```
````